# Should I allow a TFS housekeeping file to be overwritten during a merge?

Tags: tfs, merge, xp-mode, msscci

I am trying to merge one project into another using TFS' MSSCCI Provider in XP Mode. These are "legacy" (in the sense that a Pterodactyl is a legacy avian) projects built and maintained in Visual Studio 2003.

I get a few conflicts about the local file being writable, but based on what I could glean from a bing search, I can just go ahead with the overwriting in most cases.

However, I have a special case: a file that, based on its name, is a TFS "housekeeping" file, namely mssccprj.scc:

[image]

I don't want to hose up my TFS connections and so am wary of overwriting this file. Should I or not? And if not, what is my option for saying, "never mind, this isn't really a conflict"? It seems as if I either "resolve the conflict" or the merge will fail.

### UPDATE

I have the same issue/question with a file named "vssver.scc"

Comment: which version of TFS are you on?

Comment: I don't know - how can I tell? It's ancient, I know that, going along with my XP Mode / Visual Studio 2003 experience with this project. I [have to] use the MSSCCI Provider.

Comment: So am I - how can I tell? I imagine I have two different versions - the one in use with XP Mode / VS 2003, and the one that still lives on in some fashion in our VS 2013 code (we recently switched to GIT, but I think TFS is still involved somehow).

Comment: Look where team explorer is pointing to. Then find that server

Comment: How do I determine where Team Explorer is pointing? I know the name of the server, but I don't think that would tell me or you anything ("ducati") <= a name somebody here chose.

Comment: You need to log onto the server and see what version is installed.

Comment: By "logging onto the server" do you mean connecting to the server? If not, how does one log onto the server?

Comment: post your connection string, and we should be able to tell if it's pre 2010

Comment: I don't use a connection string, I select a menu item in Visual Studio